# Combinatorial Optimization William Cook et al

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, network-flow

I'm working on exercises from Combinatorial Optimization by Cook et al. and I'm a little stuck on how to proceed with the following problem:

Given digraph $G, u\in \textbf{R}^E$, and $r,s\in V$, find $R, r\in R\subset V\backslash\{s\}$ such that $u(\delta(R))-u(\delta(\bar{R}))$ is minimized.  (Hint this is much easier than the minimum cut problem).

I'm a little thrown by the hint as proceeding like the minimum cut problem was my initial instinct.  I'd be quite interested in a more efficient approach to this.  Thanks for any insight.

---

Ok, I thought more about this question and I think I have a solution that I've given below, however it seems like it disregards the hint.  Any thoughts?

Clearly we know the flow entering $R$ and the flow leaving $\bar{R}$ must be at most than the capacity of the edges in $\delta(R)$ and $\delta(\bar{R})$ respectively, i.e.

$x(\delta(R))\leq u(\delta(R))$ and $x(\delta(\bar{R}))\leq u(\delta(\bar{R}))$

So if we subtract these two inequalities we get:

$x(\delta(R))-x(\delta(\bar{R}))\leq u(\delta(R))-u(\delta(\bar{R}))$

Notice that if $r\in R$ and $s\in\bar{R}$ that the LHS is just the net flow into $s$, denoted $f_x(s)$.  So if we maximize the flow into $s$, that is find the maximum flow for $G$ that value for $f_x(s)$ will be the minimum value for the RHS.  Thus if we find the $R$ that corresponds to the minimum cut set for the maximum flow $f_x(s)$ that will minimize the RHS.

My issue is that this feels like it violates the hint?

---

As @RobPratt pointed out my earlier argument is flawed.  What if instead we construct a new directed graph $G^+$ such that $V(G^+)=V(G)$ and $E(G^+)=E(G)\cup\{(v,u) : (u,v)\in E(G)~\text{and}~(v,u)\notin E(G)\}$ if for each edge $(u,v)\in E(G)$ with $(v,u)\notin E(G)$ and assign capacities to each $e\in E(G^+)$ by the following procedure: if $e$ is also an edge in $G$, then $u_{G^+}(e)=u_{G}(e)$. And if $e\in E(G^+)$ but not $e\notin E(G)$, then $u_{G^+}(e)=0$.

Now construct a second directed graph from $G^+$, denoted $G^*$, as follows $V(G^*)=V(G)$ and

$E(G^*)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} (u,v) & \text{if}~ u_{G^+}(u,v)-u_{G^+}(v,u)\geq0\\(v,u) & \text{if}~ u_{G^+}(v,u)-u_{G^+}(u,v)\geq0\\\end{array}\right.\\$

And assign capacities to the edges in $E(G^*)$ as follows: if $u_{G^+}(u,v)-u_{G^+}(v,u)\geq0$, then $u_{G^*}(u,v)=u_{G^+}(u,v)-u_{G^+}(v,u)$.  And if $u_{G^+}(u,v)-u_{G^+}(v,u)\leq0$, then $u_{G^*}(v,u)=u_{G^+}(v,u)-u_{G^+}(u,v)$.

Now, if we find the maximum flow across $G^*$, the corresponding minimum cut $\delta(R)$ gives us,by construction, $u_{G^*}(\delta(R))=u_{G^+}(\delta(R))-u_{G^+}(\delta(\bar{R}))=u_G(\delta(R))-u_G(\delta(\bar{R}))$.

Comment: Does an expression like $u(\delta(R))$ have a hidden summation in it??

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes, $u(A)$ means $\sum_{(i,j)\in A} u_{ij}$.

Comment: You can add two inequalities, but subtraction is not valid.  As a simple example, consider that $1\le 2$ and $1\le 3$, but $1-1 \not\le 2-3$.

Comment: @RobPratt I see.  Valid point.  I've constructed a new argument to avoid that oversight.